# Pagination in gridview Yii2 without page reload

Tags: ajax, gridview, pagination, yii2, pjax

I am a Yii2 beginner. I have almost completed all of my grid-view except for pagination. I tried to use pjax but can't find a solution.

Comment: Use GridView widget. Don't reinvent the wheel. Pjax use simple - just before GridView you should run Pjax->begin and after GridView you should run Pjax->close

Comment: Thank you @EvgeniyTkachenko ,and i used gridview between run pjax->begin and pjax->close but when click for next page for next data browser is reload.

Comment: done... i forgot to put pager in layout 
$layout = "{summary}\n{items}\n{pager}"

Answer (score 8):

You have to set timeout for Pjax (default is 1000 ms). Sometimes it is not enough and plugin will reload the page completely.

```
<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(['timeout' => 10000, 'clientOptions' => ['container' => 'pjax-container']]); ?>
<?= GridView::widget([
 // ... configuration here
]);?>
<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::end(); ?>
```

[see here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-pjax.html#$timeout-detail)

Answer (score 2):

Put your code between Pjax::begin and Pjax::end this work for every thing not only the gridview

```
<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(); ?>
<?= GridView::widget([
 // ... configuration here
]);?>
<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This May Help...:)

Just start and end Pjax thats all..

```
<?php 
    use yii\widgets\Pjax;
     <?php Pjax::begin(['id'=>'type_id']); //id is used for jquery opertaion  ?> 
    <?php echo GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'filterModel' => $searchModel,
            'columns' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

                //'id',
                //'user_id',
                'type',

                ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
            ],
        ]); ?>
    <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```